# Java set containsall performance

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, hashset

I am trying to compare two hashsets in java, both of them contains several characters, but I need to do it a lot of times (10^5~8), so I am trying to improve the performance. 
In detail, what I want to compare is whether set A contains B or set B contains A and their size difference <= 2. Here are the two methods I come up with,

1. use set containsall method,
2. since the set can only contains 26 letters, I am not using hashset anymore, I use bit operation, if the virtual set has 'a', then I give 1; if it has 'b', I give 1<<1, which is 2; if it has 'c', I give 1<<2, which is 4, then I add all the values together as the value for the set. Then I do xor and count the number of 1 in the result.

Which method would be better?

Comment: Is it not performant using `containsAll`, or is this an optimization based on a perceived bottleneck?

Comment: The second one, probably. But this is really easy to settle: try both, report back with the results, we'll all learn something. By the way, you don't have to count the bits, you can determine whether there are at most two bits by removing the rightmost set bit twice (look up the trick) and then comparing against zero.

Comment: Agree with other comments, but also want to point you at Java's `BitSet` class. You can avoid having to think about all the shifting, bit counting, and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly the second approach is the one to use.

I would do it something like this:

```
public class IntBitSet {

  private int set = 0;
  private final int firstChar = (byte) 'a';
  private final int lastChar = (byte) 'z';

  public int size() {
    return Integer.bitCount(set);
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return set == 0;
  }

  public boolean contains(char c) {
    assert c <= lastChar && c >= firstChar : c + " is not a valid value.";

    return ((set >>> (c - firstChar) ) & 1) != 0;
  }

  public void add(char c) {
    assert c <= lastChar && c >= firstChar : c + " is not a valid value.";

    set = set | (1 << (c - firstChar));
  }

  public void remove(char c) {
    assert c <= lastChar && c >= firstChar : c + " is not a valid value.";

    set = set & ~(1 << (c - firstChar));
  }

  public boolean containsAll(IntBitSet c) {
    return (this.set & c.set) == c.set;
  }

  public void clear() {
    set = 0;
  }
}
```

and the unit test.

```
  import org.junit.Test;
  import static org.junit.Assert.*;

  public class IntBitSetTest {

    public IntBitSetTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSize() {
      System.out.println("size");
      IntBitSet instance = new IntBitSet();

      int count = 0;
      for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c+=3) {
        instance.add(c);
        count++;
      }

      assertEquals(count, instance.size());

    }

    @Test
    public void testIsEmpty() {
      System.out.println("isEmpty");
      IntBitSet instance = new IntBitSet();

      assertTrue(instance.isEmpty());

      instance.add('g');
      assertFalse(instance.isEmpty());

    }

    @Test
    public void testContains() {
      System.out.println("contains");
      IntBitSet instance = new IntBitSet();

      for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        instance.add(c);
      }

      instance.remove('o');
      instance.remove('u');
      instance.remove('s');

      assertTrue(instance.contains('a'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('d'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('i'));

      assertFalse(instance.contains('o'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('u'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('s'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
      System.out.println("add");
      IntBitSet instance = new IntBitSet();
      instance.add('b');
      assertFalse(instance.contains('a'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('b'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('c'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('d'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('e'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('f'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('g'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('h'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('i'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('j'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('k'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('l'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('m'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('n'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('p'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('q'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('r'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('s'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('t'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('u'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('v'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('w'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('x'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('y'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('z'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemove() {
      System.out.println("remove");

      IntBitSet instance = new IntBitSet();

      for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        instance.add(c);
      }

      instance.remove('e');

      assertTrue(instance.contains('a'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('b'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('c'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('d'));
      assertFalse(instance.contains('e'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('f'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('g'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('h'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('i'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('j'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('k'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('l'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('m'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('n'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('p'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('q'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('r'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('s'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('t'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('u'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('v'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('w'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('x'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('y'));
      assertTrue(instance.contains('z'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testContainsAll() {
      System.out.println("containsAll");

      IntBitSet instance1 = new IntBitSet();
      IntBitSet instance2 = new IntBitSet();
      IntBitSet instance3 = new IntBitSet();

      for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c+=3) {
        instance1.add(c);
        instance2.add(c);
        if(c % 2 == 0)
          instance3.add(c);
      }

      assertTrue(instance1.containsAll(instance2));
      assertTrue(instance1.containsAll(instance3));
      assertFalse(instance3.containsAll(instance1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testClear() {
      System.out.println("clear");
      IntBitSet instance = new IntBitSet();

      instance.add('z');

      instance.clear();
      assertTrue(instance.size() == 0);
      assertTrue(instance.isEmpty());

    }
  }
```